# creating PDF file using express and nodjs

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

I am working to create an endpoint to generate a pdf file from html content and return it to client using nodejs and express.

for that I am using puppeteer as following :

```js
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda')
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core')
  let browser = null
  
  // const executablePath = await chromium.executablePath

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      executablePath:'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
      headless: true
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setContent('<html><body><h1>Hello, PDF!</h1></body></html>')
    const pdfStream = await page.pdf({format: 'A4' })
    res.send(pdfStream)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({error})
    return res.status(500).send({
      status: 0,
      error: 'download failed'
    })
  } finally {
    if (browser !== null) {
      await browser.close()
    }
  }
}
```

Why do I always receive an empty pdf file when calling the endpoint from the browser ? the file is downloaded but its always empty.

when adding the path to `page.pdf({path:...})` the file is successfully generated locally(on server) but its being sent empty to browser (client)

Comment: You're sending the `pdfStream` in your response. That's the problem. You need to set the **proper content type and encoding**. for ref: `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');`, etc.

Comment: @mandy8055 yes I tried it before   , but when adding this line to set the content type , the downloaded file is not opening with error message "It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize."

Comment: Did you also add [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)?

Comment: yes , I added the following changes `res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename=demo.pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    res.status(200).send(pdfStream);`

Comment: I know it would be difficult but is it possible to reproduce your issue(with minimal example) on some online sandboxes maybe repl.it or https://codesandbox.io/? Since other parts of your code looks ok as per me.

Comment: I am not sure if this would help , but I am building the express app using serverless framework . I also tried to read an existing pdf file (without generating it using puppeteer) but I got the same results , an empty file

Comment: First, you need to understand what is your point of failure. Try to use the local path and save the converted PDF locally. If PDF file is empty you have an issue with puppeteer/chromium and need to looks once again on the external browser you are using. Otherwise, if PDF is fine, you deal with the problem of delivering it and need to look at the express portion of your code, which is not part of your snippet at all. Do a bit of work on your own to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov As I mentioned at the end of the question , the PDF is successfully saved locally with its content when I provide a local path for the generated file so I believe the issue os not related puppeteer/chromium. It can be related to the serverless framework that I am using but until now its not clear

Comment: Excellent, if PDF conversion part is working fine for you, you should be posting information (including the code you wrote for Router to hook up the PDF conversion handler) on express, which you said you are using as the web server. For the response you still need to use appropriate headers as in your comment above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express/Puppeteer: generate PDF from EJS template and send as response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255357/express-puppeteer-generate-pdf-from-ejs-template-and-send-as-response). Just replace `const html = await ejs.renderFile("invoice.ejs", {user: userData});` with your raw HTML, `const html = "<your html>"`.