# In nodejs Rest api call, puppeteer page evaluate not returning the response and throws the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, puppeteer

1. In nodejs Rest api call, puppeteer page evaluate not returning the response and throws the error.
2. How to return object after executing all the steps, without async

```
app.get("/api/register", function (req, res) {
 
  res =  page.evaluate((res) => {
    
   
      webex.meetings
        .register()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Authentication#register() :: successfully registered");
         return res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully Registered" });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error( "Authentication#register() :: error registering", error);
       return   res.status(400).json({ message: "Successfully Registered" });
        })
        
   
  }, res);
});
```

error
:\Users\sansubbu\git\webRTC\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:115
const stringifiedMessage = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, message, { id }));
^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
|     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
--- property 'socket' closes the circle Recursive objects are not allowed.
at JSON.stringify ()
at Connection._rawSend (C:\Users\sansubbu\git\webRTC\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:115:41)
at CDPSessionImpl.send (C:\Users\sansubbu\git\webRTC\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:320:82)
at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (C:\Users\sansubbu\git\webRTC\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:211:46)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but `res` is not going to work inside an `evaluate` call. Return  a promise from your `webex.meetings().register`  and `await` it in Node land, then call `res`, or use `page.exposeFunction` to enable triggering `res.json()` from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

`res` is a complex, circular structure that only works in the Node environment. Even if you could, passing it to the browser console via `page.evaluate()` would take it out of Node, where it belongs, leaving it in an environment where it doesn't make any sense (browsers can't respond to requests as if they were a server).

Instead, try returning a boolean and branching on that on the Node side, where `req`/`res` are in their natural environment:

```js
app.get("/api/register", async (req, res) => {
  const success = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    try {
      await webex.meetings.register();
      return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (success) {
    console.log("Authentication#register() :: successfully registered");
    return res.status(200).json({message: "Successfully Registered"});
  }

  console.error("Authentication#register() :: error registering", error);

  // probably not the message you want but left as-is...
  return res.status(400).json({message: "Successfully Registered"});
});
```

This is untested since you haven't provided a complete, reproducible example.

`page.exposeFunction` is another possible tool for triggering Node code based on a condition in the browser, but that seems like overkill here.

Finally, I'm not sure what `page` is, but typically you need a different page for each request. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67910262/6243352) for suggested Express + Puppeteer boilerplate.