# How to use Puppeteer browser globally with fastify router?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, fastify

index.js

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

// Route 1 # Google
fastify.get('/google', async (request, reply) => {

   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       headless,
       args: ['--no-sandbox'],
   })

   const page = await browser.newPage()
   await page.goto('https://google.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const body = document.querySelector('body').textContent
      return { body }
  })
})

// Router 2 # Bing
fastify.get('/bing', async (request, reply) => {

   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       headless,
       args: ['--no-sandbox'],
   })

   const page = await browser.newPage()
   await page.goto('https://bing.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const body = document.querySelector('body').textContent
      return { body }
  })
})

// Run the server!
const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen({ port })
    console.log(' Fastify Server Listening on Port 3000')
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

start()
```

Is there a way to use `browser` and `page` globally? Above example each router generate `browser` every single request. I think it is not proper use case - will occurr memory leak I guess. Is there a way initiate `browser` on first launching server and reuse it each router?

Comment: See [the example at the bottom of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67910262/6243352). It's for Express but it's virtually the same as fastify. I'm pretty sure you'll want to make a new page per request, though. Otherwise, what's supposed to happen if two clients connect at the same time? Eventually, you might want a queue or puppeteer-cluster to avoid _too_ many clients connecting at once. As an aside, you can use `await page.content()` rather than the whole `await page.evaluate(() => {` thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use decorator for this: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Decorators/#decorators

```js
fastify.get('/bing', async function foo (request, reply) {

   const browser = fastify.browser()
   // or const browser = this.browser() when you use named handler function

   const page = await browser.newPage()
   await page.goto('https://bing.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const body = document.querySelector('body').textContent
      return { body }
  })
})


const start = async () => {
  try {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       headless,
       args: ['--no-sandbox'],
   })

    fastify.decorate('browser', function () {
      return browser
    })
    await fastify.listen({ port })
    console.log(' Fastify Server Listening on Port 3000')
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}
```

As suggested in the question's comments, beware of multiple requests and too many tabs opened.