# Improving performance of a Puppeteer scrape

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

```js
app.get("/home", async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const pageNumber = req.query.page || 1; 
    await page.goto(`https://gogoanimehd.io/?page=${pageNumber}`);

    const animeInfo = await page.$$eval(".items p.name", (elements) => {
      return elements.map((element) => element.textContent);
    });

    const animeEpNo = await page.$$eval(".items p.episode", (elements) => {
      return elements.map((element) => element.textContent);
    });

    const animeimage = await page.$$eval(".items img", (elements) => {
      return elements.map((element) => element.getAttribute("src"));
    });

    const animeEpLink = await page.$$eval(".items a", (elements) => {
      const uniqueLinks = new Set();
      elements.forEach((element) => {
        const href = element.getAttribute("href");
        if (href) {
          uniqueLinks.add(href);
        }
      });
      return Array.from(uniqueLinks);
    });

    const animeCard = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < animeInfo.length; i++) {
      let card = {
        animeInfo: animeInfo[i],
        animeEpNo: animeEpNo[i],
        animeimage: animeimage[i],
        animeEpLink: animeEpLink[i],
      };

      animeCard.push({ ...card });
    }

    await browser.close();

    res.json(animeCard);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred while scraping data." });
  }
});
```

I'm working on a personal project and I need to scrape some data from a website. I tried cheeerio but the data doesn't show up. However, when I use puppeteer, it works very nicely.

The problem is, after getting the data, I'm sending it in a route as JSON, but this takes a lot of time to respond--10 to 15 seconds. How can I fix that?

I try doing many things, like improving my code, but it still takes a long time. I want to fix it so that it won't take 12 to 15 seconds to respond.

Answer (score 3):

The data appears to be there statically, so you can just use Cheerio:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "https://<your URL>/?page=1";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$(".last_episodes li")].map(e => ({
      name: $(e).find(".name").text(),
      episode: $(e).find(".episode").text(),
      img: $(e).find("img").attr("src"),
      link: $(e).find("a").attr("href"),
    }));
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Time:

```
real 0m1.279s
user 0m0.330s
sys  0m0.055s
```

If you switched to Puppeteer because you were blocked, you can try adding a browser user agent header before resorting to Puppeteer.

If you do need to use Puppeteer, the typical optimizations are:

1. [Share an always-open browser between routes and open new pages for each one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67910262/6243352). This mitigates browser startup time.
2. [Use `page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"})`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded).
3. [Block all assets or scripts that aren't necessary for the data you want](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#not-blocking-images-and-resources) (images, fonts, CSS, etc).
4. Disable JS if you don't need it to get the data (although you can typically convert such scripts to axios/fetch and Cheerio).
5. Minimize the number of evaluate calls. This is micro-optimization territory, but these are fairly expensive subprocess network calls that involve the operating system.

Applying these operations can often cut browser automation execution time in half, but it'll always be higher than fetch. 10-15 seconds seems unusually high, so I'm not sure how to account for that.

Another Puppeteer note: always use `finally` to close the browser. If an error happens, your browser will never close and you'll wind up with a bunch of zombie processes leaking memory on your server.

Here's my optimized Puppeteer code:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.2.1

const url = "https://<Your URL>/?page=1";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req => {
    req.url() === url ? req.continue() : req.abort();
  });
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.$$eval(".last_episodes li", els =>
    els.map(e => ({
      name: e.querySelector(".name").textContent,
      episode: e.querySelector(".episode").textContent,
      img: e.querySelector("img").src,
      link: e.querySelector("a").href,
    }))
  );
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Time:

```
real 0m1.662s
user 0m0.313s
sys  0m0.141s
```

Enabling JS, not blocking extra requests and removing domcontentloaded gives:

```
real 0m2.431s
user 0m0.446s
sys  0m0.173s
```

with the bulk of the added time being JS execution.

Note that I'm respecting nesting in my selection. This should be more reliable than the "parallel arrays" approach, which can often get out of sync if one selector unexpectedly gathers more elements than another. I find it's also more intuitive to write the top-down nested selectors where the data for each object is already together instead of trying to glue parallel arrays together after the fact.

Comment: how does it take you to get response?

Comment: now im getting error with that code

Comment: I showed the times. What's the error?