# How can I remove JSON formatting for use in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, puppeteer

I have converted my **(scraped)** JSON response into a string for use in HTML. This program simply seeks to pull the title of a book off of Amazon, remove the JSON formatting, and output that title in regular string format within the body of my HTML.

Is there a proper way to implement one of the (replace) or (replaceAll) fragments I provided at the bottom of this thread into my code, or is there a different way to get this task done? Here is my code, and I preemptivly thank you all for the help.

**JS Code (scrapers.js):**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/scrape', async (req, res) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.amazon.com/Black-Swan-Improbable-Robustness-Fragility/dp/081297381X');

  const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="productTitle"]');
  const txt = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
  const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();
  
  const myObj = {rawTxt};

  res.json(myObj); // Send the JSON response

  browser.close();
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

**HTML Code (index.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="myObjValue"></p>
  <script>
    fetch('/scrape') // Send a GET request to the server
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const myObjValueElement = document.getElementById('myObjValue');
        myObjValueElement.textContent = `rawTxt: ${data.rawTxt}`;
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have looked online, and the main solutions I have found are applying either of these to my string-converted JSON message:

```
.replaceAll("\\{","")
.replaceAll("\\}","")
.replaceAll("\\[","")
.replaceAll("\\]","")
.replaceAll(":","")
.replaceAll(",","")
.replaceAll(" ","");
```

```
.replace(/"/g, "")       // Remove double quotes
.replace(/\{/g, "")       // Remove opening curly braces
.replace(/\}/g, "")       // Remove closing curly braces
.replace(/\[/g, "")       // Remove opening square brackets
.replace(/\]/g, "")       // Remove closing square brackets
.replace(/:/g, "")        // Remove colons
.replace(/,/g, "")        // Remove commas
.replace(/ /g, "");       // Remove spaces
```

Unfortunately, I have not been able to implement either of these solutions correctly, and each time the JSON-formated string {"rawTxt":" The Black Swan: Second Edition: The Impact of the Highly Improbable: With a new section: "On Robustness and Fragility" (Incerto) "} is output on my localhost 3000 within the browser.

I would like this to be output instead - The Black Swan: Second Edition: The Impact of the Highly Improbable: With a new section: "On Robustness and Fragility" (Incerto).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive, minimal code example. But I'm not sure I understand the problem. What do you mean by "JSON formatting"? The string is sent to the client as a value in a JSON object, the JSON string is parsed by `fetch`, then you use the `.rawTxt` property to access the string on the client and insert it into the document. At that point, there are no JSON string artifacts like brackets, quotes or commas. This is 100% normal and looks perfectly fine to me. Why would you use `.replace()` for anything? Are you seeing a problem I'm not?

Comment: I am given {"rawTxt":" The Black Swan: Second Edition: The Impact of the Highly Improbable: With a new section: "On Robustness and Fragility" (Incerto) "} I would like - The Black Swan: Second Edition: The Impact of the Highly Improbable: With a new section: "On Robustness and Fragility" (Incerto). Thanks for the response!

Comment: Please try saving and re-executing your code. I don't see any JSON artifacts in the HTML output. `.then(response => response.json())` parses it into a standard JS object. `console.log(data)` in the final `.then()` should help you debug it on the client.

Comment: As an aside, I suggest using `const rawTxt = await page.$eval("#productTitle", el => el.textContent.trim())` to get your text. `$eval` is simpler and avoids multiple calls and stale elements. No need for xpath or Element Handles. Versions I'm using, BTW: puppeteer ^21.2.1, express ^4.18.2, FF 117.0.1 (64-bit), Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: No fix, but important to mention: I am running - node scrapers.js - in my terminal to start my localhost 3000 and then simply opening localhost 3000 in my browser. Should I be running a different command, or is there another problem because I am still receiving the same JSON output? Thanks for the previous tip about eval by the way.

Comment: Ah, I understand the problem. You're not running your HTML page, you're hitting the API route directly in the browser. I'll add an answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're starting the Express server, then navigating directly to the API route at http://localhost:3000/scrape rather than viewing the HTML page, which uses `fetch` to hit the API route. That missing step means you'll see the raw JSON output from the API without the processing that the script in the HTML file does (i.e. `response.json()`, which parses the JSON into a plain JS object).

To serve the HTML page on the same origin as the server, you can adjust your server code as follows:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public')); // <-- added

app.get('/scrape', async (req, res) => {
// ...
```

Then create a folder in the project root called `public` and move `index.html` into it.

Finally, restart the server and navigate to http://localhost:3000 (which serves index.html) and you should see the expected output.

In short, your code is correct, but you might have misunderstood how to serve and view the HTML page.

---

As an aside, you can simplify your Puppeteer selector and improve error handling to ensure you always close the browser:

```js
app.get('/scrape', async (req, res) => {
  let browser;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto('<Your URL>'); // TODO: paste your URL here!
    const rawTxt = await page.$eval(
      '#productTitle',
      el => el.textContent.trim()
    );
    res.json({rawTxt});
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  finally {
    await browser?.close();
  }
});
```

Better yet, since the particular piece of data you want is baked into the static HTML, you can speed things up by disabling JS, blocking all requests except for the base HTML page and using `domcontentloaded`:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.2.1
const express = require("express"); // ^4.18.2
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));

const url = "<Your URL>";

app.get("/scrape", async (req, res) => {
  let browser;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on("request", req =>
      req.url() === url ? req.continue() : req.abort()
    );
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    const rawTxt = await page.$eval("#productTitle", el =>
      el.textContent.trim()
    );
    res.json({rawTxt});
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  finally {
    await browser?.close();
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

You can also share one browser instance across all requests. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67910262/6243352) if you're interested.

Comment: Hey, tried your suggestions and code, it immediatly popped up, hooray! But I accidently reloaded it and now every time I restart my project, run - node scrapers.js - and navigate to http://localhost:3000/scrape it will not load and just an never ending spiral of death appears as the icon of the tab. Also is there anything important to take away from the other users suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause that. is the server running Puppeteer successfully? I'd toss some logs in on the server to see where it's getting stuck, and open the network tab on the client to see if it loads the page and makes the `fetch` request to the server. Look for errors in the dev tools. Maybe try adding some non-Puppeteer content to the HTML page to make sure it's loading correctly. The other user's answer is probably ChatGPT, mostly irrelevant although not a bad idea to cache the browser, which I've mentioned here. Performance is secondary to correctness, though.

Comment: ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Cannot navigate to invalid URL
    at <instance_members_initializer> (/Users/evanoliver/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:96:14)
    at new Callback (/Users/evanoliver/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:100:16) Theres some more similar error messages after that, but this is the start of it.

Comment: OK, thinking about it for a second, assuming you're running the same code as me on the server, the site you're scraping may be blocking you if you've made too many requests in a short period of time. You can try adding a [user agent header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70936552/6243352) or testing on another site to verify that this hypothesis is true.

Comment: Ah, well I wrote `const url = "<Your URL>";`, so you'll want to plug in your scraping target URL there.

Comment: Worked, still getting JSON though. Also dont know if this is relevant but, I have a file in my project called scrapedData.json and it says {
  "rawTxt": "  The Black Swan: Second Edition: The Impact of the Highly Improbable: With a new section: \"On Robustness and Fragility\" (Incerto) "
}.

Comment: Are you navigating to http://localhost:3000 and not http://localhost:3000/scrape? The first URL accesses the index.html page which parses and renders the HTML, but the second bypasses the HTML and goes right to the API, accessing the raw JSON. You want to go to index.html and let it make the request to http://localhost:3000/scrape for you. The `scrapedData.json` file should be irrelevant as far as my answer is concerned--there's only two files: `public/index.html` and `scrapers.js`.

Comment: nope, going to scrape. Wait.... im getting something!

Comment: So peculiar, it is showing me the non json format than as the tab continues to load 10 seconds later the json format replaces it...

Comment: That should not happen. Are you sure the index.html file is identical to the one you posted here? You can use `view-source:http://localhost:3000` to ensure it looks right.

Comment: all I changed was deleting "rawTxt:" in front of the actual varibale.  Look - <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="myObjValue"></p>
  <script>
    fetch('/scrape') // Send a GET request to the server
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const myObjValueElement = document.getElementById('myObjValue');
        myObjValueElement.textContent = `${data.rawTxt}`;
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: That looks fine and I still don't have the same problem on my end. I'd check the network tab in the dev tools on the client to make sure there's only one request going to the `/scrape` route, and continue to add logs on the server to see which requests are coming in to the `/scrape` route, making sure Puppeteer is running OK and so forth, keeping in mind if the site blocks you or the selector changes, things could break at that stage. The other parts of the app should be solid, though, just a standard `fetch` to an Express JSON route..

Comment: also another note the non json only shows when I go to/scrape after loading the regular localhost 3000.

Comment: Well, as a client you'll never navigate to /scrape in your browser, just the main index page and make sure the data looks right there. As a user, you don't know that the /scrape route exists. It's a JSON API used to communicate data from the server to the client side JavaScript application running on index.html. If you expected /scrape to show HTML, then you'll want to redesign your pages and routes a bit so that /scrape serves HTML and hits an API route to get JSON, renaming the current /scrape route to something else like /api/scrape.

Comment: is there a way I can send you a screen recording of my POV?

Comment: You could, but probably the easiest way to proceed is to hop on a Zoom call. If you happen to be on Codementor, you can [hire me](https://www.codementor.io/@ggorlen) for a few minutes and I'm sure we can work it out. But if registration is a pain, no problem, I'll watch a screen capture and try to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255756/discussion-between-evan-and-ggorlen).

Answer (score -1):

Here are some ways we could optimize this web scraping code:

1. Cache the browser instance - Open the browser once and reuse it for
   multiple requests instead of launching a new browser on every
   request.
2. Use async/await instead of promises - Makes the code a bit cleaner
   by avoiding promise chains.
3. Extract constants - Move strings like the URL into constants to
   avoid duplicates.
4. Use a template literal for setting text - Avoid concatenation when
   setting the element text.
5. Error handling - Add some error handling in the scrape route in case
   the page errors.
6. Use Headless mode - Launch chromium in headless mode for faster
   processing without UI.
7. Parallelize requests - Handle multiple requests concurrently instead
   of sequentially.
8. Persistent storage - Save scraped data in a cache or database to
   avoid duplicate scrapes.
9. Streaming response - Stream the JSON response instead of building
   the full object to improve memory usage.
   Here is one way to implement some of these optimizations:

   ```
   // scraper.js
   const { URL } = require('./constants'); 

   app.get('/scrape', async (req, res) => {
     try {
       const browser = getBrowser(); // cached instance
       const page = await browser.newPage();
       await page.goto(URL);

       const title = await getTitle(page); 

       res.json({ title }); // stream JSON response  
     } catch(e) {
       console.error(e);
       res.sendStatus(500);
     }
   });

   // page-utils.js
   const getTitle = async (page) => {
     const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="productTitle"]');
     const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
     return txt.jsonValue(); 
   }

   // stream response, error handling, async/await, template literal
   ```

Comment: All of this is rather tangent to OP's question of why there is JSON formatting showing when they view the route. The main problem is that they need to serve and view their HTML. A number of these like tips like "Use headless mode" and "Use a template literal for setting text - Avoid concatenation when setting the element text." are irrelevant, OP's already using template literals and running headlessly. `res.json({ title });` isn't streaming as the comment suggests.