# Node.js: close browser if its open using Pupeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am doing processing using `Puppeteer` and I am closing the browser like using `browser.close()` for example something like this

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
  });
  try {
  // more processing
  browser.close();
  // more processing
  } catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
  browser.close();
}
```

I am using `browser.close();` in catch block, but sometimes the browser.close() is already executed in `try` block when the exception occurs.

I want to know if there is a way to check if browser.open? and issue browser.close() only in that case.

Any help in this would be really great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look about [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

You should add finally block and add there browser close :)

> The finally-block contains statements to execute after the try-block and catch-block(s) execute, but before the statements following the try...catch...finally-block. Note that the finally-block executes regardless of whether an exception is thrown. Also, if an exception is thrown, the statements in the finally-block execute even if no catch-block handles the exception.

**Edit 1**

After understanding that issue is detecting if browser is closed I edit and input solution for that problem [puppeteer : how check if browser is still open and working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105376/10310278)

Comment: I want to identify if browser is open before closing it.

Comment: ok here you go resource for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105376/10310278, from your questions I understood something different